# Using libstreaming to stream to a VLC server

Tags: android, vlc, libstreaming

I am using the [libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) library for Android. I wish to use the RTSP client in the library to stream video to a VLC server. I'm not sure how to setup the VLC server on the command line to receive the stream from the Android phone.

Let's say that I want to run the VLC server on port 5444 and I want to save the stream from the Android to a file called test.mp4. How would I do this?